# Returns a list of all four-letter words that can be constructed using the first "n" letters of the uppercase alphabet

Tags: python, list, grouping

I have a function called four_letter_list and the goal is to return a new list that has randomized 4-letter words that can be constructed using the "nth" letter of the alphabet

You cannot use built in python functions besides len, range, for loops, while loops and if-elif-else statements.

ex:
def four_letter_words(2)
returns the list
['AAAA', 'AAAB', 'AABA', 'AABB', 'ABAA', 'ABAB', 'ABBA', 'ABBB', 'BAAA', 'BAAB', 'BABA', 'BABB', 'BBAA', 'BBAB', 'BBBA', 'BBBB']

This is the code I have

```
def four_letter_words(n): #returns four letter words
    new_list = []
    alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    index = 0
    for element in n:
        while index >= 1:


    return new_list
```

I was thinking of using the group.by but we can only use those functions as stated above.

Comment: How are those randomized? It looks like you're returning all the combinations, not anything random.

Comment: How do you expect `for element in n` to work? `n` is a number, not a sequence you can iterate over. Maybe you mean `for element in range(n)`?

Comment: When I say randomized I mean they're not four letter words, they're just four letter randomized sections. Using all possible outcomes

Comment: So they're just strings, not words. Anyway, use `alphabet[:n]` to get the first `n` letters of the alphabet.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Also see Stack Overflow guidance on [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  Simply dumping your assignment here is unacceptable.  Producing all permutations of a given sequence is solved in many places on line.  We expect you to do your research before posting here: you should have a healthy attack on the problem, not an empty function body with no test cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the most straightforward way would be to use four nested loops - one per letter - with a test in the middle to make sure one of the letters matches n:

```
def four_letter_words(n):
    new_list = []
    alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    letter = alphabet[n-1]

    for l1 in alphabet:
        for l2 in alphabet:
            for l3 in alphabet:
                for l4 in alphabet:
                    if (l1 == letter) or (l2 == letter) or (l3 == letter) or (l4 == letter):
                        word = l1+l2+l3+l4
                        new_list.append(word)
    return(new_list)

print(four_letter_words(2))
```

This could be generalised to words of any length by using recursion instead of nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

There is a python standard lib function: itertools.product that does this. Otherwise, just use a 4-layer for loop.

Comment: The assignment says they're not allowed to use functions like that.

Comment: itertools needs to be imported,  technically it is not a built-in.

Comment: That's a real nitpick. It's a built-in module.

Answer (score 0):

Use 4 nested loops over the first `n` letters of the alphabet.

```
def four_letter_words(n): 
    """returns four letter words"""
    new_list = []
    alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    first_n = alphabet[:n]
    index = 0
    for c1 in first_n:
        for c2 in first_n:
            for c3 = first_n:
                for c4 = first_n:
                    new_list.append(c1 + c2 + c3 + c4)

    return new_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Using recursion:

```py
def letter_words(n, len=4):
    return [''] if len == 0 else [c + l for l in letter_words(n=n, len=len - 1) for c in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[:n]]
```